# How to display a message after form has successfully submitted

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a HTML form which is processed with PHP. I would like to display a message to let the user know that the form has submitted successfully. For now I don't mind if the page reloads or not. I would just like a 'Success!' message to appear once the form has been submitted.

Any help would be great!

PHP

```
<?php
$errors = array();
$missing = array();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $to = 'celinehalpin@hotmail.com';
    $subject = 'Web Design';
    $expected = array('name', 'company', 'email', 'phone', 'contactYou', 'interest', 'budget', 'comments');
    $required = array('name', 'email', 'contactYou', 'interest', 'budget', 'comments');
    $headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8";
    $authenticate = '-fcelinehalpin@hotmail.com';
    require './_includes/mail_process.php';
    if ($mailSent) {
        header('Location: index.php#c');
        exit;   
    }
}
?>
```

HTML

```
<div id="contactBox">

            <form name="contact" id="contactForm" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                <div id="formLeft">
                    <p>
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                        <?php if ($missing && in_array('name', $missing)) { ?>
                        <div class="warningDivLeft">
                        <span class="warning">Please enter your name</span>
                        </div>                             
                        <?php } ?>
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" tabindex="10"
                        <?php
                        if ($errors || $missing) {
                            echo 'value="' . htmlentities($name, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8') . '"';
                        }
                        ?>      
                        >
                    </p>
                    <p>                           
                        <label for="company">Company Name/Website</label>
                        <input type="text" name="company" id="company" tabindex="30"
                        <?php
                        if ($errors || $missing) {
                            echo 'value="' . htmlentities($company, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8') . '"';
                        }
                        ?>      
                        >
                    </p>
                    <p>                           
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <?php if ($missing && in_array('email', $missing)) { ?>
                        <div class="warningDivLeft">
                        <span class="warning">Please enter your email</span>
                        </div>
                        <?php } elseif (isset($errors['email'])) { ?>
                        <div class="warningDivLeft">
                        <span class="warning">Invalid email address</span>
                        </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" tabindex="40"
                        <?php
                        if ($errors || $missing) {
                            echo 'value="' . htmlentities($email, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8') . '"';
                        }
                        ?>      
                        >
                    </p>
                    <p>                           
                        <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" tabindex="50"
                        <?php
                        if ($errors || $missing) {
                            echo 'value="' . htmlentities($phone, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8') . '"';
                        }
                        ?>      
                        >
                    </p>
                    <p>                           
                        <label for="contactYou">Contact you by...</label>
                        <?php if ($missing && in_array('contactYou', $missing)) { ?>
                        <div class="warningDivLeft">
                        <span class="warning">Please select one</span>
                        </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <select name="contactYou" size="1" id="contactYou" tabindex="60">
                            <option value="" selected="selected">- select</option>
                            <option value="email" <?php echo ($contactYou == 'email') ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Email</option>
                            <option value="phone" <?php echo ($contactYou == 'phone') ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Phone</option>
                        </select>
                    </p> 
                </div>
                <div id="formRight">
                    <p>
                        <label for="interest">I am interested in...</label>
                        <?php if ($missing && in_array('interest', $missing)) { ?>
                        <div class="warningDiv">
                        <span class="warning">Please select one</span>
                        </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <select name="interest" size="1" id="interest" tabindex="80">
                            <option value="" selected="selected">- select</option>
                            <option value="new" <?php echo ($interest == 'new') ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Creating a new website</option>
                            <option value="current" <?php echo ($interest == 'current') ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Redesigning a current website</option>
                            <option value="responsive" <?php echo ($interest == 'responsive') ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Reponsive web design</option>
                            <option value="wordpress" <?php echo ($interest == 'wordpress') ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>A WordPress website</option>
                            <option value="general" <?php echo ($interest == 'general') ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>General enquiry</option>
                        </select>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="budget">My budget is...</label>
                        <?php if ($missing && in_array('budget', $missing)) { ?>
                        <div class="warningDiv">
                        <span class="warning">Please select one</span>
                        </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <select name="budget" size="1" id="budget" tabindex="90">
                            <option value="" selected="selected">- select</option>
                            <option value="100" <?php echo ($budget == '100') ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>€100 - €500</option>
                            <option value="500" <?php echo ($budget == '500') ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>€500 - €1,000</option>
                            <option value="1000" <?php echo ($budget == '1000') ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>€1,000 - €2,000</option>
                            <option value="2000" <?php echo ($budget == '2000') ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>€2,000 - €5,000</option>
                            <option value="5000" <?php echo ($budget == '5000') ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>€5,000 - €10,000</option>
                            <option value="10000" <?php echo ($budget == '10000') ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>€10,000+</option>
                        </select>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="comments">How can I help you?</label>
                        <?php if ($missing && in_array('comments', $missing)) { ?>
                        <div class="warningDiv">
                        <span class="warning">Please leave a comment</span>
                        </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="45" rows="5" tabindex="100"><?php
                        if ($errors || $missing) {
                            echo htmlentities($comments, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8');
                        }
                        ?></textarea>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div id="formSubmit">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                          <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send Message" tabindex="70">
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                    </form>
        </div>
```

mail_process.php

```
<?php
$suspect = false;
$pattern = '/Content-Type:|Bcc:|Cc:/i';

function isSuspect($val, $pattern, &$suspect) {
    if (is_array($val)) {
        foreach ($val as $item) {
            isSuspect($item, $pattern, $suspect);   
        }
    } else {
        if (preg_match($pattern, $val)) {
            $suspect = true;    
        }
    }
}

isSuspect($_POST, $pattern, $suspect);

if (!$suspect) {
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $temp = is_array($value) ? $value : trim($value);
        if (empty($temp) && in_array($key, $required)) {
            $missing[] = $key;
            $$key = '';
        } elseif(in_array($key, $expected)) {
            $$key = $temp;
        }
    }
}

if (!$suspect && !empty($email)) {
    $validemail = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    if ($validemail) {
        $headers .= "\r\nReply-to: $validemail";
    } else {
        $errors['email'] = true;
    }
}

if (!$suspect && !$missing && !$errors) {
    $message = '';
    foreach ($expected as $item) {
        if (isset($$item) && !empty($$item)) {
            $val = $$item;
        } else {
            $val = 'Not selected';
        }
        if (is_array($val)) {
            $val = implode(', ', $val); 
        }
        $item = str_replace(array('_', '-'), ' ', $item);
        $message .= ucfirst($item) . ": $val\r\n\r\n";
    }
    $message = wordwrap($message, 70);

    $mailSent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $authenticate);
    if (!$mailSent) {
        $errors['mailfail'] = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well instead of redirecting to another page you could display a message.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
header('Location: index.php#c');
```

go to:

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '?success=1');
```

then add:

```
if (isset($_GET['success'])) print 'Message sent!';
```

anywhere you want.

Comment: Thank you! This worked! However now the page reloads to the top of the page. My site is a one page site and clicking on each menu item brings you to a different section of the page. My contact form is at the very bottom. How would I go about returning to the same contact section once the page reloads, or better yet, just get the message to appear without reloading? Thank you.

Comment: Well the `#` operator tells the webpage to scroll down to that ID. So you can actually put `header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '?success=1#c');` and after refreshing, the page will scroll down to that section. Then in that section, you can print the success message. The other option is to NOT use header redirection and instead just print a message, something like `die('Thank you, your message has been sent. Press BACK to return');`

Comment: Thank you so much! This has worked perfectly. I just have one more issue. When the form is submitted with an error such as a required field is left empty, the page reloads to the top of the page rather than reloading the to the same section of the page so that the user can see the error messages. I think it was working that way before, but the new code may have changed things. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET` works, but it will always be present if they revisit the link in their history (clicking their history, browser back, or refresh)

You could set a `$_SESSION` upon success, then redirect to another page (e.g. thanks.php).

In thanks.php if session is set, and whatever criteria you wish, echo them out whatever message is relevant to the data in the session.

Then unset the session.

This way, if they click a link and come back to the thanks.php page, your script will show the session as not set, and so can produce a generic message:

> This page is for confirmation of sending stuff. You're here as you
>   refreshed the page or used your browser back button. As part of
>   security procedures, we clear the data once sent and confirmed, etc

Refreshing the thanks.php, messing with GET data, etc, etc, will do nothing. The session is not set, they get the friendly generic message.